# Checkbox need to be checked based on string values

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-checked

I am fetching data from LocalStorage as follows

```
angular.module('madMeApp').controller('campaignInDetails', function($scope) {
  var campaignToShow = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("CampaignDetails"));
  $scope.selectedDays = campaignToShow.selected_days;
});
```

I am getting selected_days value in a comma separated string e.g. Tuesday,Wednesday

Based on that value of selected_days

I want to be checked the below Checkbox,

```
<input type="checkbox" value="Monday" name="selected_days" />
<input type="checkbox" value="Tuesday" name="selected_days" />
<input type="checkbox" value="Wednesday" name="selected_days" />
<input type="checkbox" value="Thursday" name="selected_days" />
<input type="checkbox" value="Friday" name="selected_days" />
<input type="checkbox" value="Saturday" name="selected_days" />
<input type="checkbox" value="Sunday" name="selected_days" />
```

Kindly help me that how to check the checkbox using AngularJs as per the value.
In this condition I want to be checked Tuesday,Wednesday checkbox.

Thanks.

Comment: multiple input of type checkbox with the same name? I thought you only did that for input of type radio

Comment: Yes Jaromanda these are in a same group so name of these checkboxes are same.
Users can check multiple checkbox.

Comment: @Ajeet have you tried my answer?

Comment: Yes @the_mishra :) I am just trying, its really cool and will work.
Will update after trying.
Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

create a function for ng-checked which would return true or false based on you local storage string.
example :

```
<input type="checkbox" value="Monday" name="selected_days" ng-checked="dayChecker("Monday")" />
```

In controller

```
var str = "Tuesday,Wednesday";
$scope.dayChecker = function(day){
  if(str.indexOf(day) > 0){
    return true;
  } else{
    return false;
  }
}
```

Hope it would help